# Placing an image with an href in a toolbar cause problem with IE.

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-7

I have toolbar which is the topmenu of an extjs application.  At the far left of the toolbar, I want to place the company logo, and when users click on the logo, I want them to be directed to the home page.
So I have this code for my toolbar:

```
topMenuToolbar.add({
            xtype: 'box',
            html: '<a href="'http://www.mysite.com" <img src="/images/mysitelogo.jpg" /></a>'

        });
```

Everything is working perfectly in FF and Safari, but in IE 7 and 8 it's a different story.  Look what IE is doing with the code:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com" src="/images/mysitelogo.jpg" <img=""/>
```

What can I do to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...when the HTML inside the HTML tag is well formed, everything is working perfectly!
Instead of :

```
html: '<a href="'http://www.mysite.com" <img src="/images/mysitelogo.jpg" /></a>'
```

I did that :

```
html: '<a href="'http://www.mysite.com"> <img src="/images/mysitelogo.jpg" /></a>'
```

And now it's working perfect in IE and FF.

Comment: You should also use well-formed JavaScript :)